# Wireless Ethernet Bridge: Client IP address not on router dhcp table

Tags: wireless-networking, dhcp, wireless-bridge

I have a desktop computer connected to my wifi via a Linksys WES610N wireless ethernet bridge.

- Currently the bridge is assigned the IP address 10.0.0.6.
- The desktop is assigned the IP address 10.0.0.15.
- The DHCP client table on my Netgear router sees 10.0.0.6 (the wireless ethernet bridge and its corresponding MAC address)
- The router does not list 10.0.0.15 (the desktop IP address) or its MAC
- My desktop has a DHCP lease (according to ipconfig /all) that is good until sometime tomorrow.

  - Since my router is the only DHCP server on my network, I can only assume that it is issuing the ip address.

I've hunted through forum posts and documentation but I cannot figure out if the WES610N does something funky to DHCP when it bridges the connection.

I am trying to host a LAN game and even with the firewall down and antivirus disabled no one can ping me. I can ping the gateway, reach the internet and even join a game hosted on a different system on my LAN. It seems that no one can find me on my network.

Comment: What DHCP server is listed in your desktop's ipconfig /all command?  Perhaps the wireless bridge is running a mini DHCP server of its own?  Why is the PC 10.0.0.15 when the bridge is 10.0.0.6?

Comment: I was thinking that too, but 10.0.0.15 is within the DHCP pool of the router. The bridge *might* be configured to take care of it, buuuut it still shouldn't prevent others from reaching me when we are on the same subnet and my firewall is down. It's like I need to sniff the wifi traffic between the bridge and the router...

Comment: Since your PC is connected via wifi, there might be a setting on the router not allowing communication between wired LAN clients and wifi clients.

Comment: The system that was trying to reach me was also connected via wifi

Comment: My conjecture at this point is that the bridge is actually NATing (or really PATing) with the rest of the network but perhaps it is passing DHCP requests. This behavior is very reminiscent of a router. I need to see if I experience an IP conflict when I configure two devices with the same IP address, one plugged into the bridge, one plugged into the router. I also need to see if two devices plugged into the switch on the bridge can communicate with each other (there is a 4 port switch on the bridge).